# How to see all device list in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

In our App we're using FCM, so Firebase analytics is also working. 
However, from the dashboard, we can only see top devices.

[image]

Is there a way to see more details about devices?

- All the models
- All OS
- Region of all the devices?
  etc.

For instance, we want to verify whether some users are being tracked in analytics (by their models), but can't find anyway to do that.

Comment: You can also use the traditional analytics dashboard and view more data: https://analytics.google.com/

Answer (score 116, accepted):

On Analytics -> Dashboard, clicking the three vertical dots then "Download CSV" will give you a CSV with all devices, OS versions, countries, languages, and more, as well as the user distribution for each.

[image: download csv]

It may also be under the share button (3 connected circles) -> Download File -> Download CSV

[image: 2022 report location]

[image: list of devices]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Firebase is still missing basic features like drill down inside the dashboard - a standard in the Google Analytics dashboard. Would be nice to see that data in the dashboard instead of a CSV, especially since Google will begin sunsetting the GA SDK for mobile in October.

Comment: Ok, I’ve exported csv from Audiences screen and I got minimal details in it. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

There is one way to see the list of devices and OS. In the screenshot you uploaded, click on the `Add Filter -> User Property -> {Device Model, Device Brand, App Version, OS Version etc.}` will be listed there.

[image]

If you have not specified any User Properties your self then also, firebase is Automatically collected user properties. Check the list of properties automatically collected by firebase.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en

Note: If firebase has collected any of the properties itself you will as I mentioned above.

Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. In my case I found that page empty! What could be the problem?

Comment: @HamzehSoboh There are couple of things,
1. Is your Firebase Integration is correct? If yes than
2. according to firebase documentation it takes at least 4 hours to reflect analytics data on the portal however I found that in the beginning right after firebase integration, it took around 24 hours for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting all analytics well except user properties, I mean automatically collected ones.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh Is your app in production? Are you seeing App Version, user property value?

Comment: I know I'm super late, but if you download the data as CSV, all the data is there in raw format.

Comment: @TharakaDevinda Ah, didn't see your comment! My answer covers that (much better imo) approach.

Answer (score 20):

Is there any way to download this report

If you hover your mouse over the grey 'other' bar, you can see a more detailed breakdown of the rest of the devices without needing to download the data as a CSV file.

[image: Image showing user usage breakdown by device on Firebase Analytics]

Comment: Accept this answer

Comment: My [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989043/608312) provides steps to download the report, since you asked.

Answer (score 12):

You can see the device information (model and OS) on Firebase `Dashboard` page, in the `Device` tab of the last card

[image: Firebase device list]

Answer (score 5):

You can see them on Google Analytics as well if you have it linked with your Firebase project. The path is **Technology** -> **App** -> **Device Models**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can see the device list in Firebase Analytics. In **dashboard** -> **device model** click in view device model. You can see list of all the devices with details.

[image]